# Null response for PublishingPageImage, REST call through declarative workflow 2013

Tags: workflow

I am getting `null` HttpResponse while executing the following call from SharePoint declarative workflow 2013.

HttpStatusCode returns "OK" but still it returns `null` response.

```
http://site:1023/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items(10)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=PublishingPageImage
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The List Items endpoint does not expose the `PublishingPageImage` column, so you would need to make two requests. First, you call that `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items(10)/` endpoint to get `FieldValuesAsHtml.__deferred.uri`, then you can make a request to the URI you obtained in your first call to get the `Image` field.